# @nativescript-community/ui-mapbox : Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0

Tags: nativescript, mapbox-gl

I'm trying to use [@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox) plugin in my nativesctipt app.

After adding the plugin to my application

```sh
ns plugin add @nativescript-community/ui-mapbox
```

```xml
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:map="@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox" navigatingTo="navigatingTo">
  <StackLayout>
    <Label text="Nice map, huh!" class="title"/>
    <ContentView height="240" width="240">
      <map:MapboxView
          accessToken="your_token"
          mapStyle="traffic_night"
          latitude="52.3702160"
          longitude="4.8951680"
          zoomLevel="3"
          showUserLocation="true"
          mapReady="onMapReady">
      </map:MapboxView>
    </ContentView>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

When running the `tns run android` command, I get the following error:

```js
Build file '/Users/Mac/lete/letesell/platforms/android/app/build.gradle' line: 575
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Could not find com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-accounts:0.7.0.
Required by:
    project :app
    project :app > com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.2.0
```

Comment: any luck with this ? am having the same issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generate a token with Downloads:Read permission (see [detailed doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#configure-credentials))
2. Add this to your App_Resources/Android/app.gradle and replace DOWNLOAD_TOKEN with the one you generated :

```json
repositories {
  maven {
    url 'https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven'
    authentication {
      basic(BasicAuthentication)
    }
    credentials {
      // Do not change the username below.
      // This should always be `mapbox` (not your username).
      username = "mapbox"
      // You can store secret token in gradle.properties for more security
      password = "DOWNLOAD_TOKEN"
    }
  }
}
```

3. Change minSdkVersion to 21 (or whatever [the doc](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency) says) in your App_Resources/Android/app.gradle